# 3D cross-correlation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I need to calculate 3D cross-correlation in MATLAB. Anyone know which function I should use? For 2–D cross-correlation it has `xcorr2`, but I don't know about is 3D.

Comment: @chaohuang: I have no idea about it, can you please help me? I thought that I may use convn!

Comment: @chaohuang: MATLAB has convn, but I am not sure that it do the same work as 3D cross-correlation or not! Do you know any example code for this aim?

Answer (score 11):

Correlation is similar to convolution except that one does not need to flip an input about the origin (but correlation needs taking the complex conjugate of one of the operands), so for 3D real matrices, you can use `convn(x3d,y3d(end:-1:1,end:-1:1,end:-1:1))` to compute 3D cross correlation.

Comment: if the question was helpful you should mark it as best answer :)