# how 2D and 3D Auto-Correlation can be calculated in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics, signal-processing

I need to compute 2D and 3D auto-correlation between matrices A and B in MATLAB. Is there any function that can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D cross-correlation in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309509/3d-cross-correlation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

auto-correlation is implemented in MATLAB as a special case of cross-correlation. Just use xcorr2(a)for 2D auto-correlation, and convn(a,a(end:-1:1,end:-1:1,end:-1:1)) for 3D.

Comment: @ chaohuang: Yes, you are right. Actually I was looked for another function, but it seems that the best ones the those.