# How to find Correlation of an color image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

How to find Correlation of an color image. Horizontally, vertically and diagonally. I have an encrypted image of size `<256x256x3 uint8>`, and I want to select pixels from each image (R,G,B) and measure the correlation. I'm creating an interface for my project. How can I display these results on interface?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309509/3d-cross-correlation-in-matlab

Comment: i did. but i m not getting this convn(x3d,y3d(end:-1:1,end:-1:1,end:-1:1))

Comment: what are x3d and y3d here..

Comment: How are you calculating the correlation?

Comment: >> xed = R(1:end-1,1:end-1);  % All but the last row and column
yed = R(2:end,2:end);      % All but the first row and column

randIndex = randperm(numel(xed));  % A random permutation of the integers from 1 to numel(x)
randIndex = randIndex(1:256);     % Pick the first 4096 indices
xRand = xod(randIndex);            % 4096 random values from x
yRand = yod(randIndex);           

% Compute the Correlation coefficient of x and y
red_xy = corrcoef(xRand(:),yRand(:));
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Edit your question; code in comments is unreadable.