# Calculate shortest distance to selected points in 3D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, distance

I have a very large 3D image stored in a matrix (approx. `500x500x40` voxels) in Matlab. In this matrix about 30000 points are selected (suppose randomly). Suppose the selected voxels have a value of one and the non-selected points are zero. Now I need to calculate for every voxel in the entire 3D-image the Euclidian distance to the nearest selected point.

So for example in 2D, given a `4x4`matrix:

```
    selection = 0 0 1 0
                1 0 0 0
                0 0 0 1
                0 0 0 0
```

The corresponding distance matrix would be:

```
    distance = 1  1  0  1
               0  1  1  1
               1  √2 1  0
               2  √5 √2 1
```

Is there an efficient way to do this, in terms of both time and memory?

Comment: How do you define your distance? Euclidian? Are the 3 dimensions of your matrix representing coordinates in 3 directions?

Comment: Distance is indeed Euclidian. The 3D matrix is a medical scan, so every "point" in the matrix is in fact a voxel.

Comment: There are many possibilities, see i.e.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search . I was thinking about octree's, but I have no relevant experience with it.

Comment: Reshape your matrix into a `250000 x 40` matrix, then sample from this matrix to get a `30000 x 40` matrix of points, then use the above marked duplicate.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I need for every voxel in the matrix (so 500*500*40 = 10M  samples) to calculate the distance to the nearest of 30k points. Using the method you mention would require to store a 10M*30k matrix, which is not possible.

Comment: @sdbonte Right it didn't hit me about the memory storage until you mentioned it and I apologize for not seeing it properly before flagging.  I'll remove the duplicate.  I also thought that each 3D slice at one spatial coordinate was a data point, not the actual voxel itself.  Because of the huge memory requirement, you may have to resort to storing on disk or splitting up the operation over multiple processors / machines.  Either way, it's going to be rather slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know which combinations had which distances, then you could calculate the [3D cross-correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309509/3d-cross-correlation-in-matlab).

To illustrate this in 2D, take the following matrix and calculate the 2D correlation as described in the reference

```
M =
 0     0     0
 1     0     0
 1     0     0

convn(v,v(end:-1:1,end:-1:1)) =
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     2     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

One can read off the distances between the ones because the correlation matrix here can be understood as the differences in indices. The central column in *convn* means the horizontal distance is zero. Likewise, the middle row means zero vertical distance. As a result, the central value gives you the amount of zero distance values, which is the sum of ones in your matrix. The two ones correspond to a vertical distance of 1 between the ones in M. One combination has a positive distance and the other combination has a negative distance.

As a result, you now have all the distances, but they contain the horizontal and vertical directions too. But you can still process that as you wish.

A way to calculate all possible squared distances without a for loop would be

```
n = size(M,1) = 
 3

tmp = repmat([-(n-1):(n-1)].^2,2*n-1,1)
d2 = tmp+tmp' =
 8     5     4     5     8
 5     2     1     2     5
 4     1     0     1     4
 5     2     1     2     5
 8     5     4     5     8
```

Both matrices together contain basically the histogram of distances.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but how would one use this in practice? I'm indeed not interested in the combinations. But I don't really see how I can use the `convn` command for this problem.

Comment: I don't think this will work. For instance, for the selected point, given in matrix M: `M = [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 0 0]`, the output would be: `distance = [1 sqrt(2) sqrt(3); 0 1 2; 0 1 2]`. If I use the `convn` command, I still would need to calculate the Euclidian distances myself, and perform a for-loop over all 10M voxels, which would be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If your points are given as coordinates X = n x 3, you can use

```
D = pdist(X,'euclidean')
```

to efficiently calculate all combinations of distances.

Comment: If I store all my voxels (10M) and selected points (30k) in a vector `X` of size `(10M+30k) x 3` and run the `pdist`command, this would result in a matrix of size `10M*(10M-1)/2 = 5e13`, which gives ofcourse "Out of memory" issues.